# Getting 400 error status code on client_credentials Spotify API request

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, spotify

I'm dealing with Spotify's API but not succeed to automatically get a new access token.

```js
function api() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials',
    headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic myClientIdEncodedToBase64Format:myClientSecretEncodedToBase64Format'
     },
    success: function(data) {
     console.log('Succes ->', data);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log('Error -> ', error);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm getting a 400 error. If [i refer the doc][1], '400: Bad Request - The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The message body will contain more information'.

What am i doing wrong here ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your pseudo code seems to imply that you are base64 encoding the clientId and  clientSecret separately, then concatenating them. This is wrong. You need to concatenate them together *first*, then base64 encode the whole string.

Comment: See the 'Header parameter' section of the table under this link: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#2-have-your-application-request-refresh-and-access-tokens-spotify-returns-access-and-refresh-tokens

Comment: Also, according to that link `grant_type` should be sent in the request body, not the URL

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan ;). So i put myClientId:myClientSecret in a base64 converter and pasted it next 'Basic' in my header. For grant_type, i remove it from url (now it looks like -> url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token') and a line below i put grant_type: 'client_credentials' . What's wrong again ?

Comment: Please edit the question to show your new code. It sounds like you need to put `grant_type` in the `data` property of the request, not its own one

Answer (score 0):

Here my code. I add data :

```js
function api() {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', 
            data: 'grant_type=client_credentials',
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Basic myClientIdAndMyClientSecretConvertedToBase64'
            },
            success: function(data) {
              console.log('Succes ->', data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
              console.log('Error -> ', error);
            }
          });
        }
```

Comment: Ohhh fine !!! It works ! The data parameter " data: 'grant_type=client_credentials' " works. But on network window in my browser, i had in preview the response that said something like 'invalid_client'. When i converted my client_id and my client_secret, there was just a space that fails the match with the API :)